# Are inferences made on a set of samples (from the population) ONLY intended to describe that set of samples?

Tags: inference, sample, population

Are inferences made on a set of samples (from the population) ONLY intended to describe that set of samples?

Suppose you have measurements on the height of 1000   giraffes from zoos across the world. You calculate the mean, the standard deviation and the 75th quantile of these measurements. You find that in these 1000 giraffes that you measured, the average height is 15ft and the 75th quantile is 17ft.

Based alone on these 1000 measurements - does this give you any reason to believe that all giraffes in the world (i.e. the population) have an average height of 15ft and 75% of giraffes are shorter than 17ft?

Or is this an impossible question? Or do you need access to expert knowledge (e.g. zoologists) who help you determine if the giraffes that were measured are actually representative of the population?

As an example, suppose I generate 1000 random numbers from a normal distribution with mu = 5 and sigma = 1. I call these 1000 numbers the population.

Of these 1000 numbers, I randomly choose 100 of them and give them to my friend. My friend takes the mean and 75 quantile of these 100 numbers - it is possible to mathematically show that the mean and standard deviation of these 100 numbers will be close to the original 1000 numbers.

But how can this be done in the giraffe problem? Is this where you need to start using Bayesian methods and attempt to confirm if your 1000 measurements are close to prior knowledge of giraffe heights?

Can these 1000 giraffes be used to make inferences about the true population of giraffes (which by default can never be measured)? Or do these 1000 giraffes only represent the 1000 giraffes measured?

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of inference is to use known information (data) to guess (estimate) unknown information about something greater than the known; you *infer* something about an unknown quantity.

Comment: Valid inferences would depend on the sample being representative of the population that you want to draw inferences about.  It might be helpful to read about [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)).

Comment: I suppose giraffes in zoos are systematically well fed, don't know about giraffes in the wild. Depending on the zoo, a giraffe in captivity might get less exercise than one in the wild. No idea if such factors might affect heights of adult giraffes you sample. Best if you confine your conclusions to heights of giraffes is zoos. With a sample of 1000, how close are you to a 'census' of zoo giraffes?